# Firefox spell checker stopped working, even though enabled

Tags: macos, firefox

Again my spell checker in Firefox (on Mac) stopped working.

I already checked under: Tools > Options, Section Language

1. "Check your spelling as you type" is ON
2. When I click on [Choose] I see a dictionary.

Nevertheless, when I type text in text boxes, e.g., in Gmail, typos are NOT marked with red squiggly lines.

Any suggestions what else I could check?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes websites will use WYSIWYG and 'ContentEditable' editors instead of standard textboxes (textareas) because they support rich text formatting and other features. Your first task is to work out whether spell-check is working correctly in regular textareas, such as those here at StackExchange. If that works, then you know the issue is with GMail. If it doesn't work, then we could go down the `about:config` route to make sure everything is set up properly, or make a new Firefox profile to rule out any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance that Firefox isn't running : Hold down the Shift key when beginning Firefox. In the event that Firefox is running : 3-bar menu => ' ? ' (at the base of the dropdown) => 'Restart with Add-ons debilitated'. At that point OK the restart. ... You can see which lexicon is chosen on the off chance that you right-click in a book zone and open the Languages sub menu.